# check what os your servers running?

Tags: operating-system

How can I check what OS my servers are running?

Comment: By reading the documentation you made when setting them up.

Comment: That depends on what OS your server is running.

Comment: If you are ssh-ing on them, it is some unix. An `uname -a` command says what you want. If you are rdesktopping on it, it is a windows, so win/E, right click on "My Computer", and...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Windows servers, you can have some info with the "srvinfo" command

On linux, try "uname -ra"

Comment: or "lsb_release -a" on Linux, too.

Comment: `msinfo32` works on just about every version of Windows for the last decade; the `uname` command works on almost all *nix platforms.

Comment: On Linux `cat /etc/issue` will give you more details about the distribution. There are also some special files: SUSE: `/etc/SuSE-release`, RedHat: `/etc/redhat-release`.

Comment: cool - did not know about srvinfo

Comment: Srv info is also useful for getting the server's uptime by the way